# Restoring Deleted Flash Builder 4 Project

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, restore, data-recovery

I was just putting the finishing touches on a flex project that loads files from a second project.

In attempting to delete a second project, I somehow deleted the project I needed. I confirmed that I wanted to delete the files. I have a backup but it is too old to be worthy of a roll-back.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you on Windows or MAC? Because if you cannot use eclipse functionality to restore the project then you have to use a software like GetDataBack to HOPEFULLY recover your files

Comment: Generally you can Use: Right Click in Package Explorer -> Restore from local history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Eclipse's [Restoring a Deleted Workbench Element](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-64.htm) option, but it wont works if you have deleted **.metadata** folder from **workspace**.

also see for visual help http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1181287.htm

Hope it Helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using the Eclipse IDE. I am using the standalone app from Adobe.

Comment: Adobes Flex/Flash Builder is customized version of eclipse for flex development, see http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html states "Adobe® Flash® Builder® 4.5 Premium software is an Eclipse™ based development tool for rapidly building expressive mobile, web, and desktop applications using ActionScript® and the open source Flex framework. Use professional testing tools to build higher performing applications."

Comment: ALL Flex/Flash builder are built on Eclipse and specifically Flash builder 4 on Eclipse Helios, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder

Comment: Ok. Looks like this actually did work. The problem was as follows. I had deleted an entire project folder. So, there was nothing for me to "click" in order to restore the project. Luckily, one of my other projects depended on it, so I got some of the files back through doing a restore on that project. A few small things were lost, but generally I'm happy as can be. If one deleted an entire project folder without any dependencies, I'm not sure the restore option would work. Also, just to point out to anyone else trying this: use the contextual menu not the main bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is why version control exists....

Anywho, you can always look into [software hard drive recovery](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=software%20hd%20re&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=software%20hdd%20recovery).